# linear span of linear in C_0(R)

Tags: real-analysis

We consider the set $C_0(\mathbb R)$ of real continous functions $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with $\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=0$ endowed with the supremum norm.
Is there $f\in C_0(\mathbb R)$ such that the linear span of $f(2^k \, \cdot \,)$, $k\in \mathbb N$, is dense in $C_0(\mathbb R)$? in $\{f\in C_0(\mathbb R), \ f(0)=0\}$?

Comment: Could you add a little context: where does this question come from, what have you tried or proved yet?

Comment: That seems to be a natural variant of the translates problem https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290631/set-of-translations-of-a-real-function-having-a-dense-linear-span?rq=1 but i am not sure one can adpat the proof which is based on fourier analysis...